# Regularity of solution to Fokker Planck equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces, linear-pde, parabolic-pde

Suppose that $\rho \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n \times (0,T))$ for every $T < \infty$ is a weak solution of the PDE
\begin{align}
\partial_t\rho &= \Delta \rho + \text{div}(\rho\nabla\Psi(x))\\
\rho(t = 0) &= \rho^0
\end{align}
where $\Psi \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is given and $\Delta$ denotes the Laplacian; that is,
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \rho\left(\partial\xi - \nabla\Psi \cdot\nabla\xi + \Delta\xi\right)d x d t + \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\xi(0)\rho^0d x = 0
\end{equation}
for all $\xi \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R})$.

I am trying to understand how to prove that this weak solution $\rho$ is in fact a classical smooth solution.

The paper "The Variational Formulation of the Fokker-Planck Equation" http://www.imati.cnr.it/savare/Ravello2010/JKO.pdf  sketches this argument, but I am having trouble understanding one part. In particular, they obtain the following expression on page 15, Equation (55):
\begin{align}
(\rho\eta)(t_1) &= \int_{t_0}^{t_1}\left[\rho(t)(\Delta\eta - \nabla\Psi\cdot\nabla\eta)\right]*G(t_1-t)dt\\
&\quad + \int_{t_0}^{t_1}\left[\rho(t)(2\nabla\eta - \eta\nabla\Psi\right]*\nabla G(t_1 - 1)dt\\
&\quad + (\rho\eta)*G(t_1 - t_0)
\end{align}
for all $\eta \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and for a.e. $0 \leq t_0 < t_1$, where $G(x,t) = \frac{1}{(2\pi t)^{n/2}}e^{-|x|^2/2t}$ is the heat kernel.

After a few straightforward computations, they show that $\rho \in L^p_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n\times(0,\infty))$, $p < \frac{n}{n-1}$.

Then, in the following line, all they say is "We now appeal to the $L^p$-estimates [18, section 3, (3.1), and (3.2)] for the potentials
in (55) - [*the above integral equality*] - to conclude by the usual bootstrap arguments that any derivative of $\rho$ is in
$L^p_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n\times(0,\infty))$, from which we obtain the stated regularity condition ($\rho \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n\times(0,\infty)$).

Could someone provide a good explanation generally for how a bootstrapping argument would work with $L^p$ estimates, and specifically in this particular case. Also how do $L^p$ estimates from reference [18], (which is O. A. Ladyzenskaja, V. A. Solonnikov, and N. N. Uralceva, *Linear and Quasi–Linear
Equations of Parabolic Type*, American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 1968) come into play.

Any elucidation on this or suggestions for reading would be greatly appreciated!

NOTE: This question was originally posted on Math StackExcahnge a few months ago (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/843901/regularity-of-a-weak-solution) and a few days ago by me (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/941505/regularity-of-the-fokker-planck-equation?lq=1) which I have deleted since I came to know of the earlier post. Since there have been no replies  I have slightly modified the earlier question and posted it here.

Comment: I am interested in this problem too, did you come to a solution?

Comment: No I never figured out the details of the bootstrapping argument. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Not really, but the $L^p$ estimates they refer to might be those in Chapter IV Section 3 of the book Ladyzenskaja, Solonnikov, Uralceva, "Linear and Quasi–Linear Equations of Parabolic Type" (there are actually many sections 3 in that book)

Comment: Thanks. I will have a look at the reference again :).

Answer (score 0):

A bootstrap argument is given in the proof of Lemma 10.7 of a paper of Mei-Montanari-Nguyen: [https://web.stanford.edu/~montanar/RESEARCH/FILEPAP/mean_field.pdf](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Emontanar/RESEARCH/FILEPAP/mean_field.pdf)

The authors only show $C^{1,2}$ derivatives exist classically under their set of assumptions, but it should be clear how to proceed with smoothness conditions to get infinite regularity. (Also $L^\infty_\text{loc}$ is nicer than $L^p$ since it's invariant under multiplication.)

I don't quite follow their step 5 and don't understand why equations 10.52 and 10.53 are correct. I think we should have, for example, for 10.52,
$$
D_t [\varphi_1 \ast_2 G] = \Delta \varphi_1 \ast_2 G - \varphi_1
$$
by $(D_t - \Delta) G = \delta_{0,0}$.
So in order to estimate $D_t^2 \rho$ one needs to estimate $D_t\varphi_1$, which again depends on the time-regularity of the drift.
This is no-problem in the JKO case, as the drift is time-independent.
Also there may be some sign errors in their proof, but I haven't checked carefully.

This is an answer to a question older than my math career since undergraduate. Hope it helps someone at least!

Edit: I don't think the heat kernel estimate 10.51 is correct for $p = \infty$. See the equivalent condition of an $L^1$ or $L^\infty$ multiplier on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplier_(Fourier_analysis)